# How to make a list comprehension with the group() method in python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to write a little script to clean my directories. In fact I have:

```
pattern = re.compile(format[i])
...
current_f.append(pattern.search(str(ls)))
```

and I want to use a list comprehension but when I try:

```
In [25]: [i for i in current_f.group(0)]
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So how to make a list comprehension using `group()`? Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?:

```
[f.group(0) for f in current_f]
```